# Cannot use lib.Const (constant 16777216 of type lib.Version) as lib.Version

Tags: go, webassembly, tinygo

I've come across an odd error. I have this larger project that compiles fine with the typical `go build`. However when I switch to TinyGo (v0.8.0). I get the above error from this code:

```
func main() {

    _ = lib.NewObject{
         Version: lib.Const,
    }
}
```

I changed the names to be less confusing but the symbols are completely identical. `lib.Const` is a constant of a `lib.Version`. And neither are pointers.

I understand this is a very specific question in the sense that it's in the realm TinyGo. This is more "for the record"... plus I even had to create the "tinygo" tag because this question is so specific. But to add further detail:

- It has been compiling before the above code was added.
- The build command in exact is `tinygo build -target=wasm -o build/out.wasm src/main-wasm.go`

Comment: shouldn't `lib.Version` just be `Version` if `Version` is  field in `NewObject`?

Comment: @AyushGupta Oops! fixed.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug with the compiler: https://github.com/tinygo-org/tinygo/issues/726

It stems from importing the same package twice under different names. In this case, it was:

```
// file1:
import "./lib"

// file2:
import "../lib"
```

The above made 2 instances of the package "lib". This is normally okay to do when working with the normal Go compiler. But TinyGo does not have mechanisms in place to deal with this properly.

It is recommended to append to the `$GOPATH` to prevent the use of relative paths:

```
// file1:
import "lib"

// file2:
import "lib"
```